# How do I use tig to view the diff for a file which is changed but not commited?

Tags: git, tig

In git, it is `git diff <file path>`, but what about in tig?

In tig, in the status view, highlighting a file (staged or unstaged) and pressing <kbd>D</kbd>, diffs the last commit. I think it should diff the uncommitted file against the last committed version of that file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a hack, you can do `git diff <file path> | tig` and see it.

On the `status` section in `tig` you can see both the staged and unstaged changes (say, `git diff` vs `git diff --cached`) pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> over the file in each of the sections it appears (under "Changes to be committed" or "Changed but not updated").

It may be a nice feature to just `tig diff -- <file path>` but, well - go ahead, code it :)

Comment: Thanks. <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the file was the answer.