# How do I see combined diff for a range of commits in tig?

Tags: git, github, tig

Github shows a combined diff of all the commits made on a branch in a pull request. e.g. [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15365/files) has three commits and Github shows a combined diff for all those three commits.

In git itself I can do something like `git diff HEAD~<n>` to see a combined diff of `n` commits.

How do I do the same in tig?

Comment: I guess what you're after is this feature request: https://github.com/jonas/tig/issues/338

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following "[How do I use tig to view the diff for a file which is changed but not commited?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20575950/6309)", the possible workaround for now would be:

```
git diff HEAD~<n> | tig
```

The [tig manual only mentions diff options](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/manual.html#diff-options), but doesn't allow to diff anything else but the previous commit.